# Append list value to corresponding value in another list

Tags: python, list, csv

So I'm trying to attach a bunch of values in a huge list to their corresponding headings stored in another list.  For example, right now I have a list with only the headings (e.g. ['Target'],['Choice']) and I want to take values corresponding with those headings (e.g. 'Target':3, 'Choice':1) and append them to the corresponding value in the headings list while also stripping off the headings from the values in the second list--so everything after the ':' needs to be attached to it's corresponding value in the original list.  Then I want to take each of these strings in the new list (e.g. [Target: 1, 2, 1, 3 . . .]) and import them into a column in a csv or excel file.  I'm admittedly a bit of a noob, but I've worked really hard thus far.  Here is what I have that doesn't word (excluding exporting to csv, as I have no idea how to do that).

```
key_name = ['distractor_shape','stimulus_param','prompt_format','test_format','d0_type','d1_type','d2_type','encoding_rt','verification_rt', 'target', 'choice','correct','debrief','response','CompletionCode']    

def headers(list):      
  brah_list = []    
  for dup in list:
    z = dup.count(',')
    nw = dup.split(',',z)
    brah_list.append(nw)
  return brah_list

def parse_data(filename):
  big_list = []
  with open(filename) as f:
    for word in f:
      x = word.count(',')
      new_word = word.split(',',x)
      big_list.append(new_word)
  return big_list

b_list = parse_data('A1T6RFUU0OTS0M.txt')
k_list = headers(key_name)

def f_un(things):
  for t in things:
    return t

h_list = f_un(k_list)

def f_in(stuff):
  for sf in stuff:
    for s in sf:
      print(s)
    z = 0
    head_r = "h_list[z]"
    if s.startswith(head_r):
      s.strip(head_r)
      h_list.append(s)
    z += 1
  print(stuff)


f_in(b_list)
```

Comment: Your should really considered using dictionary. It can have a value and a key, which is what i believe your trying to achieve with list.

Comment: and provide inputs and outputs and expected outputs at least. Hoping that your code sample is a [mcve]

Comment: Also stick to one question at a time. First figure ask your first question(the one above), then ask your second question, how to add your strings to a CSV file.

Comment: Could you share an example of what's in the file and what output you want?

Comment: Could you please clarify your exact question?

Comment: Perhaps this will make it more clear: List_A = ['HeadingA', 'HeadingB', etc], List B = ['HeadingA': Value, 'HeadingB':Value, 'HeadingA: Value_1, 'HeadingB': Value_2, etc].  What I want is List_C = ['HeadingA': Value_1, Value_2, Value_3, 'HeadingB': Value_1, Value_2, Value_3, etc].  Then I want to take the contents of List_C and append each Heading with it's values to a column in a CSV file.

Comment: @DartmouthDude82 That really does not make things any clearer. `List_A` makes sense. `List_B` and `List_C` don't... what you've written isn't valid Python syntax, and I can't guess as to what you want. Maybe `List_C` is a dictionary with string keys and list values? E.g. `{'HeadingA': ['Value_1', 'Value_2', 'Value_3'], 'HeadingB': ['Value_1, 'Value_2', 'Value_3'], ... }`? I really think it would help more if you would just tell us what's in the text file and what sort of CSV you want to have.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you have a list, and you have some corresponding values in another list retaliative to the first list. If that is the case, and assuming that all your values corresponded in the correct order you could use list comprehension:

```
lst1 = ['th', 'an', 'bu']
lst2 = ['e', 'd', 't']
#here
lst1 = [lst1[i] + lst2[i] for i in range(len(lst1))]
#here
print(lst1) #output: ['the', 'and', 'but']
```

Comment: It's impossible to understand the question as written, but I'd bet strongly against this being the goal.

Comment: @smarx Hmm... ok, took my best guess(since you have to guess given the structure of the question). You think i should delete my answer?

Comment: Maybe? Or wait for the original questioner to clarify.

Comment: I just don't want to get down-voted into oblivion when my answer doesn't work or doesn't address the problem. From the title though, it seems like he wants to match values that correspond in two list.

Comment: I clarified above: List_A = ['HeadingA', 'HeadingB', etc], List B = ['HeadingA': Value, 'HeadingB':Value, 'HeadingA: Value_1, 'HeadingB': Value_2, etc]. What I want is List_C = ['HeadingA': Value_1, Value_2, Value_3, 'HeadingB': Value_1, Value_2, Value_3, etc]. Then I want to take the contents of List_C and append each Heading with it's values to a column in a CSV file.

Comment: Does that help?  Sorry, I'm new to coding--e.g. I have to learn it for grad school.  I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having a hard time understanding the question, but if my guess is right, I think this is what you need. Note that this code uses the excellent [`tablib` module](http://docs.python-tablib.org/en/latest/):

```
from collections import defaultdict
import re

import tablib

data = defaultdict(list)

# input.txt:
# [t_show:[1471531808217,1471531809222,1471531809723,147153181‌​2159,1471531815049],‌​t_remove:[1471531809‌​222,1471531809722,14‌​71531812158,14715318‌​15046,null],param:ta‌​rget:0,distractor_sh‌​ape:square,stimulus_‌​param:shape1:star,sh‌​ape2:plus,relation:b‌​elow,negate:false,pr‌​ompt_format:verbal,t‌​est_format:visual,d0‌​_type:shape:false,or‌​der:false,relation:t‌​rue,d1_type:shape:2,‌​order:true,relation:‌​false,d2_type:shape:‌​2,order:true,relatio‌​n:true,encoding_rt:2‌​435,verification_rt:‌​2887,target:0,choice‌​:0,correct:true]

# I had to remove "debrief", "response", and "CompletionCode", since those weren't in the example data
headers = ['distractor_shape','stimulus_param','prompt_format','test_format','d0_type','d1_type','d2_type','encoding_rt','verification_rt', 'target', 'choice','correct']#,'debrief','response','CompletionCode']

with open('input.txt', 'rt') as f:
    # The input data seems to have some zero-width unicode characters interspersed.
    # This next line removes them.
    input = f.read()[1:-1].replace('\u200c\u200b', '')

    # This matches things like foo:bar,... as well as foo:[1,2,3],...
    for item in re.findall(r'[^,\[]+(?:\[[^\]]*\])?[^,\[]*', input):
        # Split on the first colon
        key, value = item.partition(':')[::2]
        data[key].append(value)

dataset = tablib.Dataset()
dataset.headers = headers

for row in zip(*(data[header] for header in headers)):
    dataset.append(row)

with open('out.csv', 'wt') as f:
    f.write(dataset.csv)

# out.csv:
# distractor_shape,stimulus_param,prompt_format,test_format,d0_type,d1_type,d2_type,encoding_rt,verification_rt,target,choice,correct
# square,shape1:star,verbal,visual,shape:false,shape:2,shape:2,2435,2887,0,0,true

with open('out.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(dataset.xlsx)
```

Comment: If `input.txt` doesn't look like your text file, please share what it *does* look like. Similarly, if the output CSV doesn't look like what you want, please share what you *do* want the CSV to look like.

Comment: Here is a random chunk of the text file: [t_show:[1471531808217,1471531809222,1471531809723,1471531812159,1471531815049],t_remove:[1471531809222,1471531809722,1471531812158,1471531815046,null],param:target:0,distractor_shape:square,stimulus_param:shape1:star,shape2:plus,relation:below,negate:false,prompt_format:verbal,test_format:visual,d0_type:shape:false,order:false,relation:true,d1_type:shape:2,order:true,relation:false,d2_type:shape:2,order:true,relation:true,encoding_rt:2435,verification_rt:2887,target:0,choice:0,correct:true,t_show:[1471531815554,. . . ]]

Comment: @DartmouthDude82 And what CSV output would you like to see for that input? (I'm especially confused about things like "param:target:0"... is that a column called "param:target" with a value of 0?)

Comment: @DartmouthDude82 What separates one "row" of the data from another? It looks like within the outer brackets, there are two items that start with "t_show:". Would you consider that the start of a second "row"? What's the purpose of those outer brackets then? Is the entire file just wrapped in that, or do the brackets ever close and reopen?

Comment: @DartmouthDude82 I'm also curious what you want to do with values like the ones for `t_show` and `t_remove` above. They look sort of like lists, but I assume they're to be treated as a single value. (E.g., in the `t_show` column, you'd expect to see `[1471531808217,1471531809222,...]`.)

Comment: @DartmouthDude82 Is there any chance you can share the full file? Or is there data in there that's not okay to share?

Comment: @DartmouthDude82 The presence of commas within values means that you won't be able to just split on them... this is going to get quite tricky to parse. (If you have any control over the format of the input, this would be a good time to execute that control.)

Comment: Give me a second and I will generate a cleaner text file.  That's what I was attempting to do with my sloppy code above.  The 'key_list' contains the headings I'm interested in.  How do I share files with you?

Comment: So the text file is something you're generating? If so, what does the data look like before that? (What's the original input?)

Comment: The original is like what I shared above.  I'm trying to generate a cleaner version, removing unnecessary headers, etc.

Comment: For any phrase that has a double set of colons (e.g. 'Param: Target: 2), I can remove the first string . . . if I can figure out how.  Also, I can remove the phrases containing 't_remove: [74879047804, 7979875987, etc]'. I think if I can figure out how to remove those values and output a new text file, I would basically have a dictionary, correct (e.g. Heading:Value)?

Comment: See if my edit helps. I used the example input you shared, though it was missing a few columns. Without the full data set, I can't really test properly, and you still haven't told us what kind of CSV you'd like to see, so I'm guessing at that part.

Comment: It might help to know more about where the data file came from... maybe it's a known format that can be parsed more cleanly than the regular expression I used. Do you know what program created that file?

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this! It was created by a Javascript program and the output is  stored in a SQL database and also was exported as text to our lab's webpage and stored in blank fields.  Is there somewhere we can chat directly?  Facebook or some sort of messenger service?  I'm not allowed to chat on here, but I assure you that I'm not a spam bot.

Comment: Thank you so much man.  You are a life saver.  Your code worked like a dream.  Brilliant!!!  Cheers!